# Shutting down Flask application from C#?

Tags: python, c#, flask

I am relaying HTTP requests from a C# application by sending JSON data to a localhost flask application, sending the requests with python, and relaying the response back to my C# application.  Needs to be done this way because the server I am dealing with is 3rd party and fingerprints SCHANNEL requests and sends back dummy data (Does this with Powershell as well, but not curl, Postman, or Python).

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = @" /k python Assets\Scripts\server.py",
    UseShellExecute = true
};
process.Start();
```

I found this solution, which uses an endpoint (/shutdown)

```
def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
```

Get a warning that it is being deprecated.  I can live with that, but my OCD makes me want to do this properly.  The warning tells me this is a hacky solution.

I am new to python/flask.  What would be a good way about going about this?

Sidenote: process.Kill() doesn't work.  Wish it did.

Answer (score 0):

process.CloseMainWindow() seems to do the trick from my initial tests.  Why process.Close() or process.Kill() do not work, is beyond me.